# CodeIgniter: Getting blank screen on update form submit. No errors

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CI and just trying to build a basic blog for practice. Everything works fine (pull all posts, individual posts, add new post, delete post) except for the update posts. The update form loads fin, but When I submit the form I get a blank page with no errors and nothing gets updated on the db. I've searched stack for solutions, but none of these seem to make a difference. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Now spits the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Post::where() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CodeIgniter_2.2.0/application/models/post.php on line 26
```

Which is the first line inside the update_post model function:

```
function update_post($postID, $data){
        $this->where('postID', $postID);
        $this->db->update('posts', $data);
    }
```

HTML form markup from the view edit_post.php:

Add new post

```
    <?php if($success==1){ ?>
        <p>Post successfully updated</p>
    <? } ?>

    <form action="<?=base_url()?>posts/editpost/<? echo $post['postID']?>" method="post">
        <p>Title
        <input name="title" type="text" value="<?=$post['title']?>" />
        </p>
        <p>Body
        <textarea name="post"><?=$post['post']?></textarea>
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Edit Post" /></p>
    </form>
```

Models:

```
class Post extends CI_Model{

    function get_posts($num=20, $start=0){
        //$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE active=1 ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,20;";
        $this->db->select()->from('posts')->where('active',1)->order_by('date_added','desc')->limit($num,$start);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    function get_post($postID){
        $this->db->select()->from('posts')->where(array('active'=>1,'postID'=>$postID))->order_by('date_added','desc');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->first_row('array');
    }

    function insert_post($data){
        $this->db->insert('posts', $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    function update_post($postID, $data){
        $this->where('postID', $postID);
        $this->db->update('posts', $data);
    }

    function delete_post($postID){
        $this->db->where('postID', $postID);
        $this->db->delete('posts');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
class Posts extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('post');
    }

    function index(){
        $this->load->model('post');
        $data ['posts']=$this->post->get_posts();
        $this->load->view('post_index',$data);
    }

    function post($postID){
        $data['post'] = $this->post->get_post($postID);
        $this->load->view('post',$data);
    }

    function new_post(){
        if($_POST){
            $data = array(
                'title'=>$_POST['title'],
                'post'=>$_POST['post'],
                'active'=>1

            );
            $this->post->insert_post($data);
            redirect(base_url().'posts/');
        }else{
            $this->load->view('new_post');
        }
    }

    function editpost($postID){
        $data['success']=0;
        if($_POST){
            $data_post=array(
                'title'=>$_POST['title'],
                'post'=>$_POST['post'],
                'active'=>1
            );
            $this->post->update_post($postID, $data);
            $data['success']=1;
        }
        $data['post']=$this->post->get_post($postID);
        $this->load->view('edit_post', $data);
    }

    function deletepost($postID){
        $this->post->delete_post($postID);
        redirect(base_url().'posts/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Missing a `return` maybe? `return $this->db->update('posts', $data);` as you did for `return $this->db->insert_id();`

Comment: @Fred-ii- He wouldn't get his page output then.

Comment: I think you meant `$this->post->update_post($postID, $data_post);`, so `$data_post` instead of `$data`.

Comment: Try die($_POST) after $data['success']=0 and see what you get. Edit: oh good catch @JeroenNoten.

Comment: @Mephoros My mistake. Seems like Jeroen (+1) hit the nail right on the head.

Comment: Excellent catch Jereon! I really need to watch when I copy and paste! Unfortunately the blank page persists though so this was not the problem (although it was A problem)!

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. @BillDukelow if you're not already using this.

Comment: Thanks! I had already tried this but nothing. Still a blank page with the same URI (as intended) to the edit form.

Comment: I'm wondering, are short open tags ON?

Comment: I just ran error reporting before declaring the model class and it spat out - 'Fatal error: Call to undefined method Post::where() in the model class' - which is '$this->where('postID', $postID);'. I have updated the model to reflect Jereon's spot, but the error persists. I'm stumped!

Comment: @BillDukelow that's an easy one to fix, add the db object to the call, it should be `$this->db->where('postID', $postID);`

Comment: Hehe! I had just noticed that! Thanks man! All working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the db call before where. Here:

```
function update_post($postID, $data){
        $this->where('postID', $postID);
        $this->db->update('posts', $data);
    }
```

Replace:

```
function update_post($postID, $data){
        $this->db->where('postID', $postID);
        $this->db->update('posts', $data);
    }
```

Comment: Spotted that a while ago after staring at the model for a good 5 minutes looking for something less obvious! Thanks man! I'll give you the win anyway!!

Comment: I appreciate i could help

Answer (score 0):

you can try to debug it by using the below line in the model function

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

It will print the last query executed, and you can try to run it manually to check whether the query is fine or not, or try to debug it by putting logs.
OR add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

In the controller to display all the errors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately nothing echo's out by adding this line to the update model and no errors when I turn on error reporting from the controller! I had tried error reporting earlier but to no avail!